Express - app.use(compression()) does not work for me in my Windows 11 - NodeJS - gzip/deflate compression
const express = require("express");
const compression = require("compression");
const app = express();

app.set("etag", false);
app.use(compression());

app.get("/data", (req, res) => {
  return res.json({
    message: "Hello, Axel Blaze, This is a test message. ".repeat(10000),
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("listening on 3000");
});


I am using compression for better bandwidth in my Nodejs projects. This works perfectly fine in my Linux Mint system but I'm not getting any size difference in network tab in resource size.

In the attached, screenshot as you can see I can't see any size difference at all. But this is working fine in Linux & I can see a significant difference in my Linux mint system. I think it is my ESET Internet Security software that's doing something that does the compression/decompression to scan the data before it reaches finally to the client. I still am not clear if this is the case but I tried to debug the response size in Wireshark & in there, I was getting the correct size.

First one is a regular request without compression in Wireshark screenshot.
Second one is a app.use(compression()) enabled and it's reduced at network level.

So, my educated guess is probably my security software is manipulating the response to scan for vulnerabilities. But I want to be sure & what's happening under the hood!


"I think it is my ESET Internet Security software" Disable it and try again?

@Marc I did that & it did not work.

The header Cache-Control set to no-transform will skip response compression.
Though the post below may not directly answer to the OP, it is still posted to record some content which may help either you or someone else now or in future at least to its possible extent.
The documentation says as the below,

This middleware will never compress responses that include a
Cache-Control header with the no-transform directive, as compressing
will transform the body.

The following code will do the compression as it is requested by the client.
const express = require('express');
const compression = require('compression');

const app = express();
app.use(compression());

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  //setting the response no-transform Cache-control
  //as it is requested by the client
  const notransform = 'no-transform';
  if (req.headers['cache-control'] == notransform) {
    res.setHeader('Cache-control', notransform);
  }
  res.json('x'.repeat(1024));
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('@s3000'));

Testing client with no-transform : Result: 1026 bytes
% curl  -H "cache-control:no-transform"  --compressed -so /dev/null http://localhost:3000 --write-out "%{size_download}\n"
1026

Testing client without no-transform : Result: 30 bytes
% curl --compressed -so /dev/null http://localhost:3000 --write-out "%{size_download}\n"
30

Observation: When no-transform was requested, the response was uncompressed - 1026 bytes, in the other case the same was compressed - 30 bytes.
Links:

Node.js compression middleware


Compression is already happening in my case as you can see from Wireshark screenshot but it's not being shown in my browser network tab because by the time it reaches that point, it's already decompressed or something like that! I want to know why this is happening!

When I worked on this, noted at times browser sees the cached download. During the work, I had turned the statement app.use(compression()) on and off many times. Many times, I had to apply "clear browser cache" to see the latest.
